# ReactJS: using object ref as {key}?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I use an object reference as {key} in ReactJS?

I've tried this:

```
let ruleList = _.map(this.state.rules, function(rule) {
      return <RuleList rule={rule} key={rule} />
    });
```

but this ends up being printed in the console:

> Warning: flattenChildren(...): Encountered two children with the same
>   key, `.0:$[object Object]`. Child keys must be unique; when two
>   children share a key, only the first child will be used.

Any way to get around this without hacks such as generating IDs for each item?

Comment: does the rule object have any property which is unique?

Comment: can you provide a sample of how rule object looks like?

Comment: { rules: [ ... ], collapsed: true, limit: 5000 }

Comment: I am asking about rule object. Meaning, one item in the rules array.

Comment: { type: 'block', value: 'a string' }

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar situation where the object has no unique id.

I ended up generating ids for the items based on object references:

```
let curId = 1;
const ids = new WeakMap();

function getObjectId(object) {
  if (ids.has(object)) {
    return ids.get(object);
  } else {
    const id = String(curId++);
    ids.set(object, id);
    return id;
  }
}

// Usage
<RuleList rule={rule} key={getObjectId(rule)} />
```

I know you mentioned that you don't want to generate ids, but I thought I'd share this since it is generic and doesn't depend on any properties in your object.

Answer (score 4):

I created a lib intended to solve this problem. It's based on the idea suggested by @amann (using a weakMap). It provides a hook, so that the weakMap is created and destroyed with the component.

Have a look to https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-key-from-object

```
import { useKeyGen } from 'react-key-from-object'

const DogList = () => {
  const keyGen = useKeyGen();

  return (
    <ul>
      {dogs.map((dog) => (
        <li key={keyGen.getKey(dog)}>
          {dog.name}
          -
          {dog.age}
        </li>
      ))
    </ul>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Update

Objects cannot be used as keys. React js requires a key to be a string or a number and should be unique.

IMO there are two ways to solve this problem (open to suggestions)

#### Option 1

Iterate through the array and create a unique index

```
var rules = data.rules;
for(var i=0;i<rules.length;i++){
  data.rules[i].key = i;
}
```

Use this key in `_.map`

```
let ruleList = _.map(this.state.rules, function(rule) { 
  return <RuleList rule={rule} key={rule.key} />
});
```

#### Option 2

Maintain a array of indices of rule objects which are not deleted.

```
var N = rules.length; 
var arrayOfRules = Array.apply(null, {length: N}).map(Number.call, Number);
```

When you delete an item remove it using [.splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice).

The component should look like this

```
let ruleList = _.map(this.state.rules, function(rule, index) { 
  return <RuleList rule={rule} key={arrayOfRules[index]} />
});
```

### ----

Since rule object has no property which is unique and key needs to be unique, add the index parameter that comes in the map method.

```
let ruleList = _.map(this.state.rules, function(rule, index) { // <--- notice index parameter
  return <RuleList rule={rule} key={index} />
});
```

Comment: this doesn't work. when you delete an item that has something before it, the rule reference gets clobbered up with the previous item's reference.

Comment: I am sorry, I didnt quite understand. Can you please explain more ?

Comment: if you have [1, 2, 3, 4] and you remove 1, you'll end up with [1, 2, 3] instead of [2, 3, 4].

Comment: @Dhiraj, can you provide any reference that keys must be string or number?

Comment: @BenCarp more info here https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps useId() which is part of React can help!

```
const ids = childrens.map(() => useId());
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-key-from-object

Answer (score 0):

This violates React rules but who doesn't:D

```js
const useObjectId = (data) => {
  const idRef = useRef(0);
  return useMemo(() => idRef.current++, [data]);
};
```

Implementation:

```js
const ruleId = useObjectId(rule);

return <RuleList rule={rule} key={ruleId} />
```

Answer (score -4):

Why do you insist on using the rule object as the key?

The easiest solution would be to use an index, returned from the underscore map function, instead. Like this:

```
let ruleList = _.map(this.state.rules, function(rule, index) {
  return <RuleList rule={rule} key={index} />
});
```

Here is a [similar topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22371947/5065931) related to the map function.

Comment: this doesn't work. when you delete an item that has something before it, the rule reference gets clobbered up with the previous item's reference.

Comment: Are all the objects different? In that case, using stringify could help. Like this: `key={JSON.stringify(rule)}`

Comment: Index as a key is an antipattern https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318

Comment: @marizikmund This worked wonders. Was trying to force a child Component to re-render based on a filters Hash changing. This did the trick perfectly. Cheers.